# Auto-Refresh large parts of webpage after Python-Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, python-2.7

I am currently developing a small application which shall be run on a Raspberry PI and generate a webpage. The webpage is currently a static HTML Page - but I guess I need to switch to some sort of a Python Webserver.

The webpage is constructed via Google Material Design Lite and features currently an iteration of a multiplication which shall be uninterrupted by the application.

I am using Python2 and OpenCV, the application is currently awaiting input from OpenCV - as soon as OpenCV detects some kind of change on the video-feed it should contact an API and after the API sends feedback the Python application should update large parts of the Webpage. The update on the webpage will add several lines in the div-grid of the webpage (add-images, texts)

After the input is gone the webpage shall revert to the initial state.

Questions:

1. How can I add several lines to the html code and auto refresh the webpage after OpenCV triggers an event?
2. Do I need to use a Python webserver for my usecase?
3. Which tools/frameworks should I use?

Thanks for your input

Edit: I could also transfer the events from OpenCV via MQTT to another framework (NodeJS?) if that would help.